# Number of closures? (Semantic clarification)

Tags: javascript, closures

Consider the following piece of JavaScript:

```
<script>
function Ninja() {
   var feints = 0;
    this.getFeints = function() {
        return feints;
    }

    this.feint = function() {
        feints++;
    }

    this.increaseByTwo = function() {
        feints = feints + 2;
    } 
}

var ninja = new Ninja();
ninja.feint();

console.log(ninja.getFeints());  //outputs one
ninja.increaseByTwo();
console.log(ninja.getFeints());  // outputs three
</script>
```

Are my right in saying the above code creates four closures

- One for Ninja - which is kinda of irrelavant.
- One for each of the inner functions inside Ninja. Each one of these three closures points to the same thing.

Or does JavaScript create two closures

- One for Ninja - which is kinda of irrelevant
- One for the three inner functions. The three inner functions share the same closure.

Answer (score 2):

All the three inner functions have a closure pointing to the same environment, and thus the variables inside. This is usually [the whole point of having closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) :

> In computer science, a closure (also lexical closure or function
>   closure) is a function or reference to a function together with a
>   referencing environment—a table storing a reference to each of the
>   non-local variables (also called free variables) of that function.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29)
>   A closure—unlike a plain function pointer—allows a function to access
>   those non-local variables even when invoked outside of its immediate
>   lexical scope.

Note that this is a frequent source of memory leaks as you aren't always aware you're keeping those references.

See what the [Google's Javascript Style Guide says about closures](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#Closures).

> One thing to keep in mind, however, is that a closure keeps a pointer
>   to its enclosing scope. As a result, attaching a closure to a DOM
>   element can create a circular reference and thus, a memory leak.

Comment: How would you proove the three inner functions share the same closure, rather than each inner function getting its own closure to the same thing?

Comment: In fact it depends on the definition (I saw many). But the practical evident fact is that they share the same environment (also called the "enclosing scope").

Comment: Sorry for being picky but this doesn't answer my question

Comment: I'm not sure you have a question, in fact. *"why does JavaScript create the 3 closures. Why not just create the one closure for the three inner functions?"* doesn't seem to make sense. For all practical matters, there is no differences between 3 closures for one environment and one closure for the 3 functions.

Comment: Please read that : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures

Comment: Can you point out relevant part? I have made question clearer.

Comment: Your question seems purely semantic. Of course you need to have an inmemory construct to make the link between a function and its enclosing scope. Some say the scope is the closure, some say the link is the closure. Practically, I see no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Just,

> One for each of the inner functions inside Ninja

If you're going to be creating a significant amount of `Ninja`s then it'd be prudent to extend using the `Ninja`'s `prototype`.

So, do:

```
var Ninja = (function () {
    function Ninja(){
        this.feints = 0;
    };

    Ninja.prototype.getFeints = function() {
        return this.feints;
    }

    Ninja.prototype.feint = function() {
        this.feints++;
    }

    Ninja.prototype.increaseByTwo = function() {
        this.feints = this.feints + 2;
    }

    return Ninja;
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZM3tH/

Comment: I am not going to be creating a significant amount of Ninjas. I want to understand the nitty gritty of closures.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you execute that code? Let's go through it stepwise:

1. You declare the `Ninja` constructor function. In the global variable scope.
2. You call the `Ninja` constructor

   1. This creates a new variable environment (containing `feints`), which lives inside the global scope in which `Ninja` was declared.
   2. Three anonymous functions are created, pointing to that variable environment.
   3. Some assignments are done and the object is returned.
3. The garbage collector checks whether it could collect the Ninja's variable environment: No, because there are still three functions alive and accessible that use it.
4. You execute the methods on your `ninja`. For each,

   1. a new, empty variable environment is created which lives inside the scope in which the function was declared
   2. The function does something, after that the local environment is garbage-collected.

So what's a closure? In my understanding, it is the fact that the private variable environment of `Ninja()` outlives the function invocation. So, your code only creates *one* closure.

Please see also @dystroy's answer, which provides useful information. And I'm sorry if I used technically incorrect terms somewhere. Afaik, the EcmaScript specification calls the "variable environments" I spoke of *execution contexts* and scopes are *lexical environments* - see [section 10](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10).